# Why does displaying a Google Interstitial Ad change the height of my NavigationBar? Xcode 11.3, iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, admob, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to display an interstitial ad in my app whenever the user taps a print button - but after dismissing the ad, my navigationBar's height has increased from 44 to 96 (on an iPhone 11 Pro Max physical test device).  The same behaviour occurs in the simulator for both iPhone 8 and iPhone 11 Pro Max.

I'd like to know both why this is happening - and how to prevent it from happening.
There is a warning message that appears in the log (see below) around the same time the height changes but I'm not sure if the warning is related to my navigationBar issue (or how to prevent it).  The ad displays successfully.

If I set "myProfile.disableAds = true", the displayInterstitialAd() function shown below doesn't run, the ad is not displayed and the navigationBar height does not change.

Here's my code:

```
    func createAndLoadInterstitial() -> GADInterstitial {
        var interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: adUnitInterstitialID)
        interstitial.delegate = self
        interstitial.load(GADRequest())
        print("Loading interstitial...")
        return interstitial
    }

    func displayInterstitialAd() {
        if interstitial.isReady && myProfile.disableAds == false {
            print("Debug:  Interstitial:  NavBarFrame: \(navigationController?.navigationBar.frame)")
            interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
            print("Debug:  Interstitial:  NavBarFrame: \(navigationController?.navigationBar.frame)")
        }
    }


    func interstitialDidDismissScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
        print("Debug:  InterstitialDelegateDidDismiss:  NavBarFrame: \(navigationController?.navigationBar.frame)")
        print("interstitialDidDismissScreen")
        interstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial() 
    }
```

And here is the output:

```
Print Button tapped...Showing interstitial ad...
Debug:  Interstitial:  NavBarFrame: Optional((0.0, 44.0, 414.0, 44.0))
interstitialWillPresentScreen
Debug:  InterstitialDelegateWillPresent:  NavBarFrame: Optional((0.0, 44.0, 414.0, 44.0))
Debug:  Interstitial:  NavBarFrame: Optional((0.0, 44.0, 414.0, 44.0))
interstitialWillDismissScreen
2020-01-23 08:36:16.387071-0500 MyApp[53938:23813577] [View] First responder error: non-key window attempting reload - allowing due to manual keyboard (first responder window is <UIWindow: 0x101c4ca10; frame = (0 0; 414 896); hidden = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x28380a880>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x2836f10a0>>, key window is <UIWindow: 0x101c26b50; frame = (0 0; 414 896); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x2838e9860>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x28368a8a0>>)
Debug:  InterstitialDelegateDidDismiss:  NavBarFrame: Optional((0.0, 44.0, 414.0, 96.0))
interstitialDidDismissScreen
Loading interstitial...
```

Answer (score 1):

It took days - but I figured it out.

Upon dismissal of the modal, full-screen interstitial ad, my NavigationBar was being regenerated.  My viewDidLoad had set "prefersLargeTitles=true" for the NavigationBar.appearance().  I (incorrectly) thought that had already been applied to the NavBar but apparently it only applies to newly generated NavigationBar's. 
 This was the cause of the unexpected change in height.  Totally my fault.  Sorry to waste everyone's time.